# rake task and action_mailer.default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rake, rake-task

When I try to use ActionMailer from rake task I'm getting this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, `set default_url_options[:host]`, or `set :only_path` to true

In my `development.rb` I have the following line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Moreover, if I put in `development.rb` this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

rake task works fine, but server crashes with this:

> config/environments/development.rb:20:in block in ': undefined method []=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

If I do this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000
```

rake task doesn't work again.

I'm confused, any suggestions?

**UPD**
i don't think that code will help, but here it is, it's that simple:

rake task:

```
 task :send_newsletter => :environment do
    Receiver.all.each { |receiver|
      NewsletterMailer.newsletter(receiver).deliver
    }
  end
```

mailer:

```
  def newsletter(receiver)
    @receiver = receiver

    mail(to: receiver.email, subject: "newsletter") do |format|
          format.html 
    end
  end
```

and the view with some `link_to xxx_url` lines, apparently which causing the error

ruby version 2.4.1

rails 5.1.3

rake 12.0.0 (but also tried 12.3.0 with no difference)

Comment: can u post yr task ?

Comment: What version of Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, that should work

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

**Update**

I don't know what is the ideal solution for this? but I have tested and it working for me

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

This also work

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

This solution based on this [**link**](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere/issues/22)

And another one is

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = '???'
```

This goes in each environment file - `development.rb`, `test.rb` and `production.rb` (and more if you have them) with the corresponding hostname in each one

[**Based Link**](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/11dfdfb)

Hope it will help

Comment: Make sure you restart your server after any update `development.rb` file

Comment: @RandomGuy See the updated answer, if not working let me know I will delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

solved with this line added to rake task. based on [fool-dev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4172515/fool-dev) answer

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```